# Delete row from SQL table (Date & Time values error)

Tags: c#, sql, delete-row

I try to write and then delete from an SQL table.  My WRITE code is OK, however my DELETE code does not work as I want.

```
//SQL_ConnectionString defined above
SqlConnection SQL_Connection = new SqlConnection(SQL_ConnectionString)

string   INSERT =  "INSERT INTO " + tbTable_DAQ.Text + " (Date, Time, Comment)";
string   VALUES =  "VALUES " + " (@Date,    @Time,   @Comment)";
string   SQL_WriteString =  INSERT + VALUES;

DateTime DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

try
{
   //get time
   DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

   //create SQL command object
   SqlCommand SQL_Write = new SqlCommand(SQL_WriteString, SQL_Connection);

   //attach values
   SQL_Write.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTimeNow);
   SQL_Write.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTimeNow);
   SQL_Write.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", "Table Access Test. ");

   SQL_Write.ExecuteNonQuery();

   //dispose & nullify SQL_Write
   SQL_Write.Dispose();
   SQL_Write = null;
}

catch (Exception eWrite) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(eWrite.ToString(), "SQL WRITE ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                       MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
}

//now delete inserted row from SQL table            
string DELETE = "DELETE FROM " + tbTable_DAQ.Text + " ";
string FROM =  "WHERE " + "Date = " + DateTimeNow  + "AND " + "Time = " + DateTimeNow 
               + "AND " + "Comment='Table Access Test.'"; //not working
string   SQL_DeleteString  = DELETE + FROM;

try 
{ 
   //create SQL command object
   SqlCommand SQL_Delete = new SqlCommand(SQL_DeleteString, SQL_Connection);
   SQL_Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
   //dispose & nullify SQL_Delete
   SQL_Delete.Dispose();
   SQL_Delete = null;
}

catch (Exception eDelete)     
{ 
     MessageBox.Show(eDelete.ToString(), "SQL DELETE ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                       MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
}
```

It give me an error.  I believe the error is due to the values of the Date and Time column.  On the WRITE code, I think the SQL table converts `DateTimeNow` to on receiving it on the `Date` (date type) and `Time` (time7 type).  However, to delete that specific row the values must match (no conversion is done) and I do not know how to get the values right.

Comment: there are errors on that code. is DateTime.Now for example. Also, why are you separating strings ? why this "WHERE "       + "Date = " ? Also, the comment in the where in the delete is different from the inserted (missing space at end), so it won't delete anything

Comment: I split the string for the ease of seeing.  Later on, I can re-use the format for other Column IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking against datetime values that are very specific. Unless you have tables records that are EXACTLY the same date and time, this will never work.

Also, you are checking both what I assume is a date field and a time field against a datetime. Why aren't you just comparing one datetime field?

Comment: I insert and then delete from table right away.  This is how I check if I can connect to the table or not.  The table has a Date and a Time column.  That is why I have to split.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert works becuase you're using SQL parameters to pass values to SQL which is great. Your DELETE probably fails on a Syntax error (it would be nice if you included the text of the error) because you're building a string and trying to execute it.

You can probably fix the delete-string by putting single-quotes around your dates but I don't even want to show you the right syntax. I'd rather you use SQL parameters again for two BIG reasons:

1. SQL will do the right conversion for you - no worries about getting the text right.
2. You're protecting yourself from SQL injection - a MAJOR security problem caused by building SQL strings and executing them.

Comment: You are correct about Syntax error.  It says:

Incorrect syntax near '11'

It is 11:49AM at that moment, so I guess that is where '11' comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Please try sending the DateTime.Now formatted to Sql proc as string

e.g. like this

```
string formatted = dateNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: I tried ToString().  It fails  with a conversion problem (string into DateTime).

Comment: inside you ToString method you need the format like this dateNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); please try again and copy the error with the datetime value

Answer (score 0):

If your autocommit isnt on you should type connection.transaction.commit. I think it would be better if you catch a status and finally test like this:

```
finally
{
  if (status)
  {
    connection.transaction.commit;
  }
  else
  {
    connection.transaction.rollback;
  }
}
```

Maybe your code try to delete a row which isnt inserted because of no commit.
But normaly it should be the datetime problem ;-)

Comment: I can see the row inserted.  However, my DELETE method fails.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
So base on n8wrl's suggestion, I do not use the strings for my SQL DELETE code.  I changed it to:

```
        //now delete inserted row from SQL table            
        string DELETE = "DELETE FROM " + tbTable_DAQ.Text + " ";
        string FROM = "WHERE " + "Date = @Date" + " AND " + "Time = @Time" + " AND " + "Comment = @Comment";
        string SQL_DeleteString = DELETE + FROM;

        try
        {
           //create SQL command object
           SqlCommand SQL_Delete = new SqlCommand(SQL_DeleteString, SQL_Connection);

           //attach values
           SQL_Delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",               DateTimeNow.Date);
           SQL_Delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time",               DateTimeNow.TimeOfDay);
           SQL_Delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment",            "Table Access Test.");

           SQL_Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();

           //dispose & nullify SQL_Delete
           SQL_Delete.Dispose();
           SQL_Delete = null;
        }

        catch (Exception eDelete) { MessageBox.Show(eDelete.ToString(), "SQL DELETE ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); }
```

and things work fine.  Thanks to Hatsoft for your help.  I think it is best to avoid the messy string method.  I do not want any injection attack.  I will be any MAJOR problem if that happens.  I mean, REALLY MAJOR.

Answer (score -1):

There are **two different** `DateTimeNow` variables that likely contain **two slightly different values** which would make an "exact match" fail.

Remove the nested one in the `try/catch` of the UPDATE that *shadows* the outer variable; I suspect it might "work" then.

However, it generally is an error to look for such an "exact" time. Perhaps you mean to look for "with the same minute" or similar?

Also, where are both the DATE and TIME columns being fed a DateTime? And what DB types do they represent?

And please **fix** the DELETE to use parameters like the UPDATE does .. there is no point regressing to not using parameters when the .NET framework handles them rather well.

Comment: I want to look for the exact HH, mm, ss.  The reason is that I INSERT and then DELETE, just to test connection to the table.  As for .NET stuffs, I am not so experienced.  I get into C# since February, and just get into .NET like 5 weeks ago.  Do not know much about it.

Comment: oh, and I think there is no .NET method to test the connection to a table.